# Two mat-paginator with single or multiple datasource is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pagination

I have a mat-table that might show up to 5/10/15 entries per page. At first, I had one mat-paginator at the bottom that worked fine. Now I'm being asked to set a paginator at the top and another one at the bottom of the table, so the user won't have to scroll all the way down to reach the paginator if they are looking for an entry that is at the top.

I tried to link both paginator to the same data source. But it didn't worked. So, tried to create 2 datasource, but it also has one limitation.

The only limitation is that the paginator at the bottom can't change items per page, since there isn't a method that lets me control that property.

Also, I couldn't set the page index or items per page properties directly (the table was not refreshing), so all the movements are achieved with some logic and paginator methods like previousPage() or lastPage().

Can anyone help me with this? I'm fine with the solution with either single or multiple datasource.

**Working code** -> [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-paginators-knhf4q)

```
<mat-paginator #paginatorTop (page)="pageEvent = handlePageTop($event)" [length]="length" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

<mat-paginator #paginatorBottom (page)="pageEvent = handlePageBottom($event)" [length]="length" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource2.paginator = this.bottomPaginator;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.topPaginator;

    this.topPaginator.length = this.dataSource.data.length;
    this.bottomPaginator.length = this.dataSource2.data.length;
  }


  public handlePageTop(e: any) {
    let {pageSize} = e;

    this.bottomPaginator.pageSize = pageSize;

    if(!this.topPaginator.hasNextPage()){
      this.bottomPaginator.lastPage();
    }else if(!this.topPaginator.hasPreviousPage()){
      this.bottomPaginator.firstPage();
    }else{
      if(this.topPaginator.pageIndex < this.bottomPaginator.pageIndex){
        this.bottomPaginator.previousPage();
      } else  if(this.topPaginator.pageIndex >this.bottomPaginator.pageIndex){
        this.bottomPaginator.nextPage();
      }
    }
  }

  public handlePageBottom(e: any) {

    if(!this.bottomPaginator.hasNextPage()){
      this.topPaginator.lastPage();
    }else if(!this.bottomPaginator.hasPreviousPage()){
      this.topPaginator.firstPage();
    }else{
      if(this.bottomPaginator.pageIndex < this.topPaginator.pageIndex){
        this.topPaginator.previousPage();
      } else  if(this.bottomPaginator.pageIndex > this.topPaginator.pageIndex){
        this.topPaginator.nextPage();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe u can upload your code to StackBlitz ?!

Comment: Yes, its there in the question itself. https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-paginators-knhf4q

Comment: issue is not with the design bro, its with the bottom pagination items per page size. data source is not updating

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to use two paginators made some changes in your code, please check it.

Here is my stackblitz code :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-paginators-svwwfj

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool man! But there is an issue with the bottom paginator for the first time. If we select for 10 page size, its not triggered

Comment: Nope, I observe some intermittent issue in between, not sure in which case exactly. I observed when testing for multiple times

Comment: @UI_Dev what you may have observe, when you are on last page and then change the page size, it will not get refresh this is behavior. To change this you need to add custom logic around this.

Comment: @GouravGarg, Yes, when I'm in last page, when I try to change 15, its not working.

Comment: Then you have to write custom method to reset the pageIndex when changing pageSize

Comment: @UI_Dev when you are in last page and try to change 15, its showing the last 5, which is correct because you have 20 entries, when you are in first page and try to change 15 then you will have 15 entries in first page and 5 entries in last page. That's the reason why it is not changing page when you are changing 15 in last page.

Comment: @GoskulaJayachandra, but what if we have another page with another paginator? If we use   "@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator", this will get applied for all the mat-paginators on the page right? So this should affect the paginators with the same data source. Can you please help with this situation.

Answer (score 1):

***This solution works if you want to show one paginator at a time***

To solve the above problem, I created a directive scroll-to. In this directive i listened for scroll events and compared the `window.pageYOffset` with element's `nativeElement.offsetTop`

`if (pageYOffset of window  < element's offsetTop)` im was setting the property `showUpperOne` true else property `showLowerOne` true.

```
import {Directive,HostListener,ElementRef} from '@angular/core'
@Directive(
  {
    selector:"[scrolledTo]",
    exportAs:"scrolledTo"
  }
)
export class ScrollDirective {

  showUpperOne=true;
  showLowerOne=false;
  constructor(private el:ElementRef){}
  @HostListener("window:scroll",['$event'])
  onScroll(){
    const elementPosition = this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop;
    const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    this.showUpperOne=scrollPosition<elementPosition
    this.showLowerOne = scrollPosition>= elementPosition;
  }
}
```

I used this directive on div which contains two paginators having the same template reference and one mat table

```
<div #mainDiv="scrolledTo" scrolledTo  class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-paginator *ngIf="mainDiv.showUpperOne" #paginator
                 [pageSize]="currentPageSize"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 (page)="pageEvents($event)"
                 [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
  </mat-paginator>
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">...
  </mat-table>
  <mat-paginator *ngIf="mainDiv.showLowerOne" #paginator
                 [pageSize]="currentPageSize"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 (page)="pageEvents($event)"
                 [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
  </mat-paginator>
```

I did set the template reference variable for div `#mainDiv="scrolledTo"`
and accessed the properties of directive to show and hide paginators `*ngIf="mainDiv.showLowerOne`" , `*ngIf="mainDiv.showUpperOne"` respectively.

This will show or hide the paginators on scroll but there will be problem with giving the paginator functionality to other paginator once one paginator hides. It has to be set to datasource again.

In order to solve this,i added currentPageSize property and did set the default value as
10   `currentPageSize=10;`. In order to reassign the paginator to datasource, i listened for the page events using `(page)="pageEvents($event)"` in template of paginator.
and in pageEvents function

```
pageEvents(event){
    this.currentPageSize=event.pageSize;
  }
```

also on scroll

```
 @HostListener("window:scroll",['$event'])
  onScroll(){
    setTimeout(()=> this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator,0)  
  }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbtcgz

Comment: Appreciate your work man! But I don't think this solution will work for my case since it has some delay when scrolling

Comment: So you didn't find solution?

Comment: And there is an issue with this approach as well. when we select the items per page dropdown of top paginator, bottom paginator goes away

Comment: No I thought we need to show and hide upper and lower paginators depending upon user's view instead of showing two paginators. If you can please reiterate the solution you want... I will try to solve

Comment: Sure, the solution which I need is to have two mat paginators one in top and another is in bottom to be synced with each other. I can able to control the table with both these paginators. I have the code where top paginator is properly working. I have issue with the bottom paginator is not triggering the data table when items per page dropdown is selected. Moreover, I have announced 500 bounty to this question to get the proper answer as soon as possible.